# Browserify: Cannot find module './support/isBuffer'

Tags: npm, browserify, uglifyjs

I am trying to minimize a js for production using Node JS. The NPM scripts are as follows

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/server.js",
    "build-js": "browserify dist/js/index.js | uglifyjs > dist/js/space/index.min.js",
    "watch-js": "watchify src/js/index.js -o dist/js/index.js -dv"
}
```

I get the following error when building viz. `npm run build-js`

```
Error: Cannot find module './support/isBuffer' from '/Users/rr/Documents/GitHub/hudddle/dist/js'
at /Users/rr/Documents/GitHub/hudddle/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
at load (/Users/rr/Documents/GitHub/hudddle/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
at onex (/Users/rr/Documents/GitHub/hudddle/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
at /Users/rr/Documents/GitHub/hudddle/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
```

I can confirm that there is no `isBuffer` module `required` directly by `index.js`. Thanks

The package json is:

```
{
 "name": "hudddle",
 "version": "0.4.0",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node scripts/server.js",
   "build-js": "browserify dist/js/index.js | uglifyjs > dist/js/index.min.js",
   "watch-js": "watchify src/js/index.js -o dist/js/index.js -dv"
 },
"dependencies": {
  "aws-sdk": "^2.311.0",
  "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
  "busboy": "^0.2.14",
  "compression": "^1.7.3",
  "debug": "^3.1.0",
  "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
  "express": "^4.16.3",
  "jwt-simple": "^0.5.*",
  "moment": "^2.22.2",
  "mongoose": "^5.2.14",
  "native-toast": "^2.0.0",
  "npm": "latest",
  "nunjucks": "^3.1.3",
  "pdf2pic": "^1.2.6",
  "redis": "^2.8.0",
  "request": "^2.88.0",
  "shortid": "^2.2.13",
  "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "browserify": "^16.2.2",
  "watchify": "latest",
  "uglify-es": "latest"
}
```